# Angular sanitize / ng-bind-html not working?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

I've got a repeater set up and can get data to display as long as there is no html within it.

I've included `angular-sanitize.js` and have tried using `ng-bind-html`

But nothing is displayed within the span, only within the `ng-bind-html` attribute. So it looks like sanitise isn't working,

I read that this needs to be added to the app dependencies but am not sure where to do so.

I've just been working through the tut on the angular site so only have a very basic controller set up at the minute.

Comment: could you show what u have tried on jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eZhnd/16/

Comment: Looks like the angular-sanatize.js file I was using was incorrect, I had taken it form the git repo, but when I took the one that's used on js fiddle it now works as expected.

Answer (score 124):

1. You need to include the angular-sanitize.js
   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js
2. Add '**ngSanitize**' to you module dependencies

   > var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
3. Don't use the `{{}}` in the attribute

   > <h1 ng-bind-html="item.title"></h1>
4. Don't use [`$sce.trustAsHtml()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml)

Comment: Thanks for putting the steps in. So much easier to follow and get figured out.

Comment: Thanks.Works perfectly.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (with 100+ upvotes why not?!)

Comment: 4. Make sure your colleagues haven't snuck in a sneaky `item.title = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.title)`

Answer (score 7):

My solution to this was to download the js file from here

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js

I had been using the one I found in the angular git repo,

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar issue but mine was a bit weird. Only input tags were not rendered while everything else including

```
<h3></h3>
<em></em>
```

did. After several hours i realised that apart from

```
angular-sanitize.min.js
```

I needed to add

```
textAngular-sanitize.min.js
```

to my project before the input tags worked. It was really frustrating so I hope this helps anyone in a similar situation

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue when using a directive and the solution was not using "replace" in the code.

`ng-html-bind' was being used on a div in the templateUrl view

```
appDirectives.directive('helpText', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    //replace: true, // With this uncommented it does not work!
    scope: {
        displayText: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/web/form/helptext',
    link: function (scope) {

    }

};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was the opposite of Seglespaan. It was to use the Bower version of Angular Sanitize.

```
bower install angular-sanitize
```

https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize