# Display output that contains HTML which is returned from a filter function

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Mark-up:

```
<div class="vpScoreInner" ng-bind-html="reason | truncate:limit:20:" ...">
```

JS:

```
filter('truncate', function($sce){
            return function(text, overall_limit, line_limit, end){
                if (!text){
                    return;
                }
                var last_blank_index = 0;
                var line_length = 0;
                var overall_length = 0;
                var processed = '';
                var componenets = text.split(' ');
                for (var i = 0; i < componenets.length; i++){
                    c = componenets[i];
                    if (overall_limit && overall_length + c.length >= overall_limit){
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml(processed + end);
                    }

                    if(line_length < line_limit){
                        processed = !!processed ? processed + ' ' + c : c;
                        line_length = line_length + c.length;
                    }
                    else{
                        processed = processed + '<br>'
                        line_length = 0
                    }
                    overall_length = overall_length + c.length;
                }

                return $sce.trustAsHtml(processed);
            }
      });
```

This filter I've implemented both truncates the text if needed, and splits it to lines of no more than x characters without cutting words in the middle.

Problem is that with normal ng-bind 
 tags are being rendered as plain text, and using the relatively-new ng-bind-html, the text is not being rendered at all.

Comment: Did you try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726938/angular-sanitize-ng-bind-html-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `$sce` here, the value returned by your filter is returned directly to the `ngBindHtml` directive which in turn will clean and render the HTML for you.

If you look at the AngularJS documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) for `$sce.trustAsHTML` it returns an object that needs to be passed to `$sce.getTrustedHTML`

```
Returns

An object that can be passed to $sce.getTrustedHtml(value) to obtain 
the original value. (privileged directives only accept expressions that 
are either literal constants or are the return value of $sce.trustAs.)
```

I think you just need to return the straight up HTML string you create and let `ngBindHTML` do the rest.

**EDIT:** Here's a simple fiddle of a filter that chops up a string into equal sizes and inserts a double break: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/LfvZf/

Comment: using ng-bind-html is correct but ngSanitize must be added to the module as well.