# ng-bind-html doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I want to show my data as html in angularjs. Here is apart of my codes :

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-controller="hosgeldinizController">
    <div id="divHosgeldiniz" name="hosgeldinizMessages" ng-repeat="hosgeldinizMessage in hosgeldinizMessages">

        <div>
            <span ng-class-odd="'degisimIcerik'" ng-class-even="'degisimIcerik alternate'" ng-bind-html="hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik">{{hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik}} </span>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesnt show as html it shows just like normal text however hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik contains html elements. What should I do to show as html?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Comment: Also  one of the div's is not closed properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get **ngSanitize** as a dependancy in your module

```
    var app = angular.module("dene",['ngSanitize']);
    app.controller("deneCtrl",function(){
       this.selam = "<p>Merhaba <strong>Angular</strong></p>";
    });
```

and use **ng-bind-html** in your view

```
<div ng-controller="deneCtrl as dene">
<span ng-bind-html = " dene.selam "> </span>
</div>
```

but be sure to include the related versions

as in

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

or if you prefer it locally you download a copy 
https://code.angularjs.org/

**point to note**

> Make sure that you have the same version of **ngSanitize** as **AngularJS** version
>   you are running ,

*well .... for some reason* if you **mixed them up** (e.g angular **1.2.23** and angular-sanitize **1.0.0**) you will end up with either a **sanitized version** in your view (it will work) but **ALOT of ERRORS in your console** or sometimes it wont render on screen at ALL :) - I believe that's what you are facing

Trust me , I 've been there :D

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me

In controller...

```
  $scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
        }
```

In the html

```
   <span ng-class-odd="'degisimIcerik'" ng-class-even="'degisimIcerik alternate'" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik)"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-controller="hosgeldinizController">
        <div id="divHosgeldiniz" name="hosgeldinizMessages" ng-repeat="hosgeldinizMessage in hosgeldinizMessages">

        <div><span ng-class-odd="'degisimIcerik'" ng-class-even="'degisimIcerik alternate'" ng-bind-html="hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik"></span></div>            
   </div>
```

If you bind to a value with HTML in it, you should use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).These bindings {{ foo }} prevent injecting actual HTML for security reasons.

Also check this [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

**EDIT**

Install [angular-sanitize](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize) and include it in your dependencies...

[Angular sanitize / ng-bind-html not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726938/angular-sanitize-ng-bind-html-not-working)

Comment: can you create a fiddle of what you did...?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<div><span ng-class-odd="'degisimIcerik'" ng-class-even="'degisimIcerik alternate'" ng-bind-html="hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik">{{hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik}} </span></div>
```

should be

```
<div><span ng-class-odd="'degisimIcerik'" ng-class-even="'degisimIcerik alternate'" ng-bind-html="hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik"></span></div>
```

without the `{{}}` expression.

Display of the content is already taken care by the `ng-bind-html` directive.

Answer (score -1):

I think using ng-bind-html-unsafe will get you what you need.

```
<div ng-repeat="hosgeldinizMessage in hosgeldinizMessages" ng-bind-html-unsafe="hosgeldinizMessage.M_Icerik"></div>
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfreitas/aHfAp/

Documentation for the directive can be found here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe)

Comment: `ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been deprecated